# Terminology for representation all of whose isotypic pieces are nontrivial

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, terminology

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional representation of a finite group $G$.  Is there an adjective describing those $V$ for which every irreducible representation of $G$ is a direct summand of $V$?

Comment: In case the field $K$ is such that $KG$ is semisimple this is equivalent to $V$ being a faithful module.

Comment: Oh dear . . . so then "$V$ is faithful" needs to be qualified as either "as a $G$-representation" or "as a $k[G]$-module" (which of course is even more confusing since "$G$-representation" and "$k[G]$-module" are synonyms).

Comment: Yes it is V is faithful as a kG-module not as a G-rep.  These are not so far since a faithful G-rep has a tensor power such is a faithful kG-module.